# Type mismatch error in VBA split function when trying to create folder paths

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create folders based on paths in a column in a worksheet. I have gone through StackOverflow and modified some code I found to fit my needs.

The issue I am having is that it works perfectly when the `strPath` range is set to a single cell (i.e. E2) but I get a type mismatch error when I set it to the column range I need `(E2:E57)` on the line: `"For Each elm In Split(strPath, "\")".`

I am still very new to VBA and while I have looked through the Microsoft documentation and searched for answers on here, I am lost.

Thank you!

```
Sub CreateDir()
Dim elm As Variant
Dim strCheckPath As String
Dim strPath As Range

Set strPath = Sheet1.Range("E2:E57")

strCheckPath = ""
For Each elm In Split(strPath, "\")
    strCheckPath = strCheckPath & elm & "\"
    If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well strPath is a range not a string.  `for each cell in strPath` (where cell is of type range) will allow you to loop over them then split on `cell.value`

Comment: So would a change look like `For Each cell In Split(strPath.value, "\")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MkDir will create new folders and subfolders at once. No need to loop through teh folder structure.

```
dim rng as range
on error resume next
for each rng in Sheet1.Range("E2:E57")
    MkDir rng.value2
next rng
on error goto 0
```

Comment: Using this I do not need to add in anything that checks if anything already exists correct? Since MkDir should ignore any paths that are already there right?

Comment: Well, it might throw an error but on error resume next tells it to skip over any errors.